# Brute force copy of PKI root certificates

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure, brute-force

If an attacker wants to create a phishing website with a fake TLS certificate, to my noob mind, there is a way to do this:

1. Create the fake website certificate
2. Create the hash for this certificate
3. Take a valid root PKI certificate with the public key of the issuer
4. Create a fake digital signature, have this decrypt with the CA public key and checks if the outcome is the same as the hash of his fake certificate.
5. Repeat step 4 till a fake TLS certificate has been created.

Of course, this will take a near-infinite amount of time, but in this hypothetical case, sooner or later the attacker will have his fake certificate.

Is a brute force attack like this one possible, or am I missing something?

Comment: This is basically asking "can you brute force the private key from the public key?". The answer is "yes". But it would take all the computers in the world several millions of years to do it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP contradicts itself in the question:  The correct claim of *"near-infinite amount of time"* means "basically never", which is obviously not the same as the claim *"sooner or later"*.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich so, then we should have a duplicate, yes? Putting aside the idiomatic contradiction, it's asking about the possibility, not probability, of deriving the private from the public key.

Comment: Likely a duplicate to [Possible to Derive Private Key from Public Key Given Enough Computing Power?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54136/possible-to-derive-private-key-from-public-key-given-enough-computing-power)